# How to replace SNOWMAN logo in Winter '17 Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-experience

When you switch to Lightning Experience there is "snowman" logo displayed for some time when LE is loaded. It might looks fancy for the couple of first time but for business applications I think it would be good to replace with something more serious (company logo for example).

I can see that it's downloaded from URL:

https://INSTANCE.lightning.force.com/img/seasonLogos/2017_winter_snowman.svg

Do you know maybe how to replace it? Is it possible at all?

BR

Jacek Bialecki

Comment: Is this you? https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000E0NQAA0

Comment: Use a chrome, ff, safari extension

Comment: @Eric - no, it's not me. But the request is the same. I just upvoted it...

Comment: @CasparHarmer - what extension do you mean precisely?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to make one. It's not hard though. Here's one I made:  https://github.com/rapsacnz/SFLoginTweak